# UndeliverableException differences in combineLatest

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two Rx compositions that I would expect to behave the same way:

Using `Observable.combineLatest(Iterable, Function)`:

```
@Test
public void testA() throws Exception {

    final Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
        .concatWith(Observable.error(new Exception("a")))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    final Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(4, 5, 6)
        .concatWith(Observable.error(new Exception("b")))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Observable.combineLatest(
        ImmutableList.of(a, b),
        objects -> Arrays.stream(objects)
            .mapToInt(x -> (Integer) x)
            .sum()).subscribe(
        x -> {},
        e -> {
            latch.countDown();
        },
        () -> {

        });

    latch.await();
}
```

Using `Observable.combineLatest(Observable, Observable, BiFunction)`:

```
@Test
public void testB() throws Exception {

    final Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(1, 2, 3)
        .concatWith(Observable.error(new Exception("a")))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    final Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(4, 5, 6)
        .concatWith(Observable.error(new Exception("b")))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Observable.combineLatest(
        a,
        b,
        (i, j) -> i + j).subscribe(
        x -> {},
        e -> {
            latch.countDown();
        },
        () -> {

        });

    latch.await();
}
```

I both cases, I am taking two streams of `Integer` and adding them in a `combineLatest`. However, the second version (`testB`) gives an `UndeliverableException` of `new Exception("b")`.

Why is this?

Comment: Both tests passed for me

Comment: Anyway, I think that the tast is not correct, but the problem is real. Because, after the first error, calling `latch.countDown()` your test ends succesfully, but actually the Observable is still running and it is emitting, I think, another error, that cannot be delivered because the previous error terminates the sequence.

Comment: I think it could be a bug in the library. Both procedures end up creating the same `ObservableCombineLatest`. The only difference seems that providing var args of observable then they are converted in an array of `ObservableSource`.